# iphone mapview bring first and last annotation to the front

Tags: iphone, mapping, mkmapview, mkannotation

I need some code which can be used outside of the mk* functions. I need to run my custom function to bring the FIRST and LAST markers in an array to the front. (so on top of all the other markers on my screen). I have tried

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[[mapView annotations]objectAtIndex: 0]];
```

I have used `[[mapView annotations]objectAtIndex: 0]` in my code and that works, but it crashes when I try to bring this to the front. Am I accessing the wrong layer or something?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13):

You're bringing the wrong things to the front. Namely, the `annotations` array is an array of objects that conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol (so of type `id<MKAnnotation>`), and they are not views.

Instead, you should be getting the view for the annotations you want, and bring those to the front:

```
id<MKAnnotation> annotation = [[mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:0];
MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
if (annotationView != nil) {
    [annotationView.superview bringSubviewToFront:annotationView];
}
```

However, you should note a couple of things:

1. `annotationView` may be `nil` if the annotation is on a point that's off screen, or if the annotations haven't finished being added to the map. However, if it is `nil`, you probably don't care if an annotation that isn't even on screen is in front or not.
2. You need to call `bringSubviewToFront` on the `annotationView`'s superview, and not on `self.view` or even `mapView`, as neither of those are the superview of the `annotationView`.

Comment: that makes sense - thank you! I need not worry about the annotation being nil as previous zoom to region code ensures that when I call this code they will be on screen (at least for a fraction - as they are drawn). I'll give the code a whirl tomorrow. Many thanks for the reply.

Comment: Important call bringSubviewToFront on annotationView.superview instead of annotationView

Comment: You might also want to add this  if(![l isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){

Answer (score 1):

This worked much better for me:

setup annotation view layer's zPosition (annotationView.layer.zPosition) in:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKAnnotationView *returnedAnnotationView = nil;
    returnedAnnotationView = [CUSTOMVIEW createViewAnnotationForMapView:self.mapView annotation:annotation];
    // SOME CUSTOM PROCESSING...
    returnedAnnotationView.layer.zPosition = 3;
    return returnedAnnotationView;
}
```

Note that I assume the default zPosition is 0.  Setting to 3 made all the 3 markers show up on top for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
For IOS 11.0 onwards use below solution to bring the Custom Callout above all annotations.

Add z position observer where you are initialising the Custom callout 

[self.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"zPosition" options:0 context:nil];


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if(object == self.layer)
    {
        self.layer.zPosition = FLT_MAX;
    }
}
```