# How to z-order MKAnnotationViews?

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I've tried the two methods found in these stackoverflow posts without luck: [post a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713221/iphone-mapview-bring-first-and-last-annotation-to-the-front), [post b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145238/how-to-define-the-order-of-overlapping-mkannotationviews).

The methods are, a, to bring the view to front from the superview, b, to set the z postion of the layer of the view.

Dose anyone know a third way?

Comment: What you need to achieve?

Comment: Control the order MKAnnoationViews are overlapping each other in my MKMapView.

Comment: I've been thinking. How can both of these methods work (in theory), would not one override the other? Dose z-position override the subview order?

Comment: I think not, z-position is layer property, one view can have any number of layers,

Comment: After some research I found out that the layer zPosition actually overrides the subview order.

Comment: Seems like MKMapView got some auto ordering going on, so the lower pins appear above, dose anyone know how to disable it?

Comment: Is there a MKOverlayLevel for MKAnnotations?

Comment: As you said @AntonHeestand, it seems that `MKMapView` do its special sauce when rendering annotation views. I tried both of the methods (subview order / zposition), both have no effect on iOS11. I still haven't found any solution to this problem. Have you? Or do I have to tell my client that is impossible to develop something as simple as showing the first annotation over the second?! What a shame...

Comment: @Martin Unfortunately I never found a solution.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, and agree that neither of the previous approaches work on iOS 11. I also tried reordering the adding of annotations, but the resulting order doesn't even reflect that. I can't see (from incidental cursory monitoring) any pattern to the ordering the MKMapView decides to give them.

Comment: An iOS 11 solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48453515/320737

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `anchorPointZ` on the `MKAnnotationView`'s layer. Keep in mind that higher values place the view *lower* in the stacking order.

```
annotationView.layer.anchorPointZ = 0
```

This works on macOS 10.13. I haven't tested yet on iOS 11, but MapKit is essentially identical on both platforms.

Comment: At first this solution was working for me, but after a bunch of tapping on my MKAnnotationViews, it's not a reliable solution :(

Comment: Did you reset the other annotations' anchorPointZ back to a value > 0? If not, then all annotations may end up with a z-postion of 0 which will revert back to the original problem.